# Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests while : Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js

Tags: web3js, synchronization, error

I am new to all this, spent over 15hrs in the past 24 hrs to deploy based on directions here : https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6

I made simple changes changes because I want to deploy to ropsten and then mainnet.  Initial migration works, but get an error at 2_deploy_contracts. I tried the fix the author mentioned in comments, it wont change anything.

I've googled and looked everything, BUT still get the same error for both networks.
Error:

> Error: Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests.  at
>   ProviderError.ExtendableError
>   (C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:9401:17)
>   at new ProviderError
>   (C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:325054:24)
>   at
>   C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:325137:17
>   at HDWalletProvider.send
>   (C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:325175:22)
>   at Object.send
>   (C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:176170:31)
>   at RequestManager.send
>   (C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:329502:32)
>   at Eth.get [as blockNumber]
>   (C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:41602:62)
>   at module.exports
>   (C:\Users\g\Documents\bootstrap-3.3.7\bootstrap-3.3.7\docs\examples\carousel\my-ico\migrations\2_deploy_contracts.js:3:48)
>   at
>   C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:176043:7
>   at
>   C:\Users\g\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\cli.bundled.js:203731:7
>   at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)

Here is my 2_deploy_contracts:

> const MyCoinCrowdsale = artifacts.require("MyCoinCrowdsale")
>   module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
>   web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber, (e, block) => {
>       if(!e) {
>         const startTime = block.timestamp + 1 //one second in the future
>         const endTime = startTime + (86400 * 20) // 20 days
>         const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000)
>         const wallet = accounts[0]
>         deployer.deploy(MyCoinCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet)
>       }   }) };

Answer (score 6):

`web3.eth.blockNumber` is synchronous.
You need to change this to `web3.eth.getBlockNumber((err, res) => {})`

Alternatively you can restructure this chain with promises:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(<WEB3_PROVIDER_URL>));

if (typeof web3.eth.getAccountsPromise === 'undefined') {
  Promise.promisifyAll(web3.eth, { suffix: 'Promise' });
}
```

Then you can do:

```
web3.getBlockNumberPromise()
.then(_blockNumber => web3.eth.getBlock(_blockNumber))
.then(_block =>   { YOUR BLOCK CODE })
```

Comment: This worked. Used 1st approach. Thank you so much. It seems that I have pending transactions that I cant get rid  and keep getting replacement transaction underpriced error. I tried MEW offline transaction to clear them out but doesn't seem to work. My address does not have any pending transactions. Any recommendations?